# grok filter (regex) to extract string within square brackets

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, logstash-grok, square-bracket

My application log entries are given below:

```
2015-06-24 14:03:16.7288  Sent request message [649b85fa-bfa0-4cb4-8c38-1aeacd1cbf74] <Request>sometext</Request>

2015-06-24 14:38:05.2460  Received response message [649b85fa-bfa0-4cb4-8c38-1aeacd1cbf74] <Response>sometext</Response>
```

I am using logstash grok filter to extract the xml content and the client token with the square bracket.

```
grok {  
    match => ["message", "(?<content>(<Request(.)*?</Request>))"]   
    match => ["message", "(?<clienttoken>(Sent request message \[(.)*?\]))"]
    add_tag => "Request"
    break_on_match => false
    tag_on_failure => [ ]
}

grok {  
    match => ["message", "(?<content>(<Response(.)*?</Response>))"] 
    match => ["message", "(?<clienttoken>(Received response message \[(.)*?\]))"]
    add_tag => "Response"
    break_on_match => false
    tag_on_failure => [ ]
}
```

Now the result looks like below

For the first log line:

```
Content =  <Request>sometext</Request>
clienttoken = Sent request message [649b85fa-bfa0-4cb4-8c38-1aeacd1cbf74]
```

For the second log line:

```
Content = <Response>sometext</Response>
clienttoken = Received response message [649b85fa-bfa0-4cb4-8c38-1aeacd1cbf74]
```

But I want the result to be like this:

```
Content = <Request>sometext</Request>
clienttoken = 649b85fa-bfa0-4cb4-8c38-1aeacd1cbf74
```

Please let me know how to extract only the strings within the square bracket without all the matching string in the pattern.

Comment: is there any way to print group index 1? `"(?<clienttoken>(Received response message \[(.*?)\]))"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use lookbehind and lookahead assertions.

```
(?<=Sent request message \[).*?(?=\])
```

likewise do the same for response message.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of the full grok syntax for matching this (with the field name)?  I seem to be having issues nesting my lookahead/lookbehind within my custom match pattern.  ie `(?<field_to_match>(?<=lookbehindregex).+?(?=lookaheadregex))` - Is this the correct approach?

Comment: @Toby did you figure it out? Facing the same issue. My lookahead and lookbehind work in REGEX tools, but with logstash they fail

Comment: @AgentX I did not.  [I asked the question here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616142/syntax-for-lookahead-and-lookbehind-in-grok-custom-pattern/55635937) and did not receive an answer.