# Syntax for Lookahead and Lookbehind in Grok Custom Pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, lookbehind, positive-lookahead

I'm trying to use a lookbehind and a lookahead in a Grok custom pattern and getting pattern match errors in the Grok debugger that I cannot resolve.

This is for archiving system logs.  I am currently trying to parse the postgrey application.

Given data such as:

```
2019-04-09T11:41:31-05:00 67.157.192.7 postgrey: action=pass, reason=triplet found, delay=388, client_name=unknown, client_address=103.255.78.9, sender=members@domain.com, recipient=person@domain.com
```

I'm trying to use the following to pull the string between "action=" and the comma immediately following it as the field "postgrey_action":

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (?:%{SYSLOGFACILITY} )?%{SYSLOGHOST:logsource} %{SYSLOGPROG} (?<postgrey_action>(?<=action=).+?(?=\,))
```

I expect to see the following output:

```
{
  "program": "dhcpd:",
  "logsource": "66.146.192.67",
  "timestamp": "2019-04-09T11:41:31-05:00"
  "postgrey_action": "pass"
}
```

Instead, from the debugger, I receive "Provided Grok patterns do not match data in the input".

How can I properly make this lookbehind/lookahead work?

Edit:  I should note that without the postgrey_action match at the end of the Grok pattern, the Grok Debugger runs and works as expected (using linux-syslog and grok-patterns).

Logstash version 6.3.2

Comment: I failed to make the regex work, even outside of grok. One solution would be to avoid using lookarounds and use something like `%{SYSLOGPROG} .*action=%{WORD:postgrey_action}.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around, I have resorted to modifying my syntax, using a custom patterns file, and referencing it in each filter using the patterns_dir directive.

**Ex.**
My pattern:

```
POSTGREY %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (?:%{SYSLOGFACILITY} )?%{SYSLOGHOST:logsource} %{SYSLOGPROG} (action=)%{WORD:postgrey_action}(,) (reason=)%{DATA:postgrey_reason}(,) (delay=)%{NUMBER:postgrey_delay}(,) (client_name=)%{IPORHOST}(,) (client_address=)%{IPORHOST:postgrey_clientaddr}(,) (sender=)%{EMAILADDRESS:postgrey_sender}(,)
```

My filter:

```
    if "postgrey" in [program]  {
        grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{POSTGREY}"}
        patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"]
        overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }
    }
```

**However, this workaround still does not answer my original question, which is, why did my initial approach not work?**

Looking at the [Oniguruma Regex documentation](https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/RegularExpressionSyntax.txt) and the [Grok filters documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok), it's not clear to me what is wrong with my original syntax or how a look-ahead/look-behind should be properly implemented with grok regex named capture. If it is not supported, it should not be documented as such.

Comment: Over a month now with very little activity.  I'm marking this answer as accepted, but would gladly accept a strong explanation as to why my original syntax specifically did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If action is always the first element of your key-value pairs you could simply match with the following custom pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} (%{SYSLOGFACILITY} )?%{SYSLOGHOST:logsource} %{SYSLOGPROG} action=(?<postgrey_action>[^,]+)
```